# remove spaces and adding '1' after specific char in text file

Tags: c#

I have a text file where I need to add '1' after the character and removing any spaces between the first two columns.
I tried to use the below query but was getting  this error

```
 201N001466  AD55JGU0604140     VOLKSWAGEN          GOLF S                   BLACK        
    201N001437  AF14HFY0604140     BMW                 520D SE AUTO             GREY  
    201N001298  AF51NSN0604140     SKODA               FABIA COMFORT 8V
```

this is the format i am looking  to add '1' after N and remove any spaces between the first 2 
columns.

```
 201N1001466AD55JGU0604140     VOLKSWAGEN          GOLF S                   BLACK         
    201N1001437AF14HFY0604140     BMW                 520D SE AUTO             GREY               
    201N1001298AF51NSN0604140     SKODA               FABIA COMFORT 8V
```

this was my query

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(
    "outfilename.txt",
    System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("outfilename.txt").Select(line =>
        string.Join(" A",
            line.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        )
    ).ToArray() - error illegal characters in path..
);
```

Comment: I would suggest splitting the Linq stuff here. Read and process your text file (in an array or list) outside the WriteAllLines methods, then write the array to output file. this way you will be able to debug a bit easier.

Comment: The values also include space in the columns. So there is no way to seperate two colums. The data format need to be get more regular. Can you do anything about this ?

Comment: the only way I can think around is to join any word after 11 character and insert 1 after 4 char.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code:

```
string[] inputLines = File.ReadAllLines("outfilename.txt");
string[] outputLines = inputLines.Select(s => Regex.Replace(s, @"^(\s*\w*?N)(\w+)\s+(\w+)", "${1}1$2$3")).ToArray();
File.WriteAllLines("outfilename.txt", outputLines);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `String.Replace`

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
foreach(line myLine in string[])
{
    String.Replace(myLine, " ", "");
    Regex.Replace(myLine, "N", "N1);
}
```

Hope it helps!